# Adding elements on a hash table

Tags: javascript, node.js, hashtable

I was reading the Grokking Algorithms and it gave me an example of a Hash Map that I couldn't replicate on Javascript... It's very simple, the only thing that I don't know is how to add the value of the ID on the "voted" variable

```js
var canVote = function(id) {
  var voted = {};
  for(let i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
    if(id in voted) {
      console.log("ID already voted!");
    } else {
      voted[id] = id;
      console.log("Voted successufully!")
    }
  }
}

var id = [10, 20, 20]
canVote(id);
```

Comment: `id` is an array (which is (imho) a terrible name because of this, it should at least be plural). What do you expect from `if(id in voted)`?

Comment: `if(id[i] in voted) {` and `voted[id[i]] = true;`

Comment: @hev1 That's not the only problem.

Comment: the if(id in voted) is to return true or false isn't it?

Comment: yes it will check if the id (which is an array) is present in the object voted. And since on first iteration it was not so it was added something like this: { "10,20,20" : [10,20,20] } .

Is it something like id[i] that you want to do?

Comment: The idea here is to do this with a hash table, because it gives the result in O(1), rather than iterating it with a for loop which gives the answer in O(n)...

Comment: You just need to use array indexing, replace id with id[i] in your loop. And it will work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of the Hash table is to find whether a value exists or not in `O(1)`. But, if you iterate over an array of `n` elements you will obviously end up doing `n` constant operations which results in `O(n)`.

Also, the logic which you used has a flaw in the loop iteration. I have modified it in the below code. Please check.

```
var canVote = function(id) {
    var voted = {};
    id.forEach(voteId=>{
        if(voted[voteId]){
            console.log("ID already voted!");
        }else{
            voted[voteId] = voteId;
            console.log("Voted successufully!")
        }
    })
}

var id = [10, 20, 20]
canVote(id);
```

Comment: Bro I don't think there is much difference between using for and forEach both will iterate over the array of n elements so O(n) in both cases. 
Plus this array element indexing i.e. id[i] was already mentioned in the comments above, could not find anything new in your answer.

Comment: It's an improved version of your approach with the flaws corrected. Also, as I see your comments I see that you are trying to get an O(1) solution for the array of items. But, that's not possible as you need to check whether the elements in array exist or not. That's what I expained in the answer

Comment: @DineshNadimpalli but in the book, Grokking Algorithms, It says that looking up an element in a size 10 hash table takes the same amount of time as looking an element in a one billion size hash table, as you can see here on this print: https://prnt.sc/tpqlst

Comment: @DineshNadimpalli maybe if I put his solution for this problem in Python it becomes easier to visualize what I'm trying to do, sorry for the number of prints... 
https://prnt.sc/tpqnr1

Comment: @JellySquare2 I understand what you are trying to say, "looking up an element" will take constant time only. But if you see the image he executed the same function multiple times with different inputs. So, while doing so he is adding elements into the object. So, first, you need to add elements if there are 'n' elements then the time taken to add 'n' elements is O(n) and as you are using hash concept looking up to check that element will take O(1)

Comment: @DineshNadimpalli Yes, I agree with what you're saying, thank you! :)